# React Native Overflow And Scroll

Tags: react-native

I started learning React Native. As far as I see, there is both an "overflow:scroll" style property and a ScrollView. Does using "overflow:scroll" in a View make it a ScrollView in React Native?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

View does not have an `overflow: scroll` property, the docs only show:

`overflow ReactPropTypes.oneOf(['visible', 'hidden'])`

The only ways to make a scrollable View are to either use ScrollView or ListView.

Comment: Right, I guess I confused it with CSS, thanks. Do you know of a resource that lists all the differences between CSS and React Native?

Comment: @JohnL. The only place that I know of would be [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/view.html#style) but it only shows the style properties in RN, and there is no comparison vs CSS that I know of.

Comment: Interestingly, the docs now have `scroll` as a supported value: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props.html#overflow. I don't really get what "`overflow: scroll` causes views to be measured independently of their parents main axis" means, though. Any idea?

Comment: This answer is out of date http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layout-props#overflow

Comment: Well, I tried and saw overflow works in react now.

Comment: List View has been removed from React Native.

Answer (score 6):

if you want **overflow: scroll** in react native then you have to use these two props

- **scrollEnabled**
- **onContentSizeChange**

like this

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { ScrollView, View } from "react-native";
const { height } = Dimensions.get("window");

export class index extends Component {
  state = {
    screenHeight: 0,
  };
  onContentSizeChange = (contentWidth, contentHeight) => {
    this.setState({ screenHeight: contentHeight });
  };
  render() {
    const scrollEnabled = this.state.screenHeight > height;
    return (
      <ScrollView
        style={{ flex: 1 }}
        contentContainerStyle={styles.scrollview}
        scrollEnabled={scrollEnabled}
        onContentSizeChange={this.onContentSizeChange}
      >
        <View style={styles.content}></View>
      </ScrollView>
    );
  }
}

export default index;
```