# How to set TextInput above of the keyboard in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I am working on an app where I am handling a form but I have some serious problem actually when I click on `TextInput` then textinput disappear . I want to set TextInput above of the keyboard . 
Thanks

[image]

*Code*

```
import React from "react";
import styled from "styled-components";
import { Platform } from "react-native";

const Fields = ({ placeholderData }) => {
  return (
    <FieldContainer>
      <TextField
        placeholder={placeholderData}
        placeholderTextColor="#0b4975"
        secureTextEntry={
          placeholderData === "Password" ||
          placeholderData === "Confirm Password"
            ? true
            : false
        }
      />
    </FieldContainer>
  );
};

export default Fields;

const FieldContainer = styled.View`
  width: 300px;
  margin-top: 20px;
`;

const TextField = styled.TextInput`
  border: 1px solid #0b4975;
  border-radius: 50px;
  padding: ${Platform.OS === "ios" ? "15px" : "8px"};
  margin-left: 20px;
  padding-left: 30px;
`;
```

Comment: So you want all the `input fields` be visible, when the `keyboard appears` right ?

Comment: @grecdev Yes, correct . when I click on input field then I want to appear input and want to show keyboard below of input

Comment: try add an `overflow-y: scroll` on the `FieldContainer` ? Check if it works.

Comment: @grecdev I am getting error: `overflow-y` is not valid style property

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39722439/react-native-overflow-and-scroll)

Comment: @grecdev I did but didn't find proper solution

Comment: you should try to place your `textfield` in `ScrollView` .

Comment: @shammi already tried but it not working please help me I am trying to fix my issue from 3 hours but I didn't figure out

Comment: okay, can you tell me where is the another code ?

Comment: @shammi https://jsfiddle.net/eys0m3du/ and child component were mentioned in question code body

Comment: sir the `scroll view` not place in child component. you should go in a parent component  where you are using this component.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/208519/discussion-between-jonas-and-shammi).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try wrapping your parent container with all the textfields in a so called `KeyboardAvoidingView`.

Here is an example:

```
import {StyleSheet, KeyboardAvoidingView } from 'react-native';

<KeyboardAvoidingView behavior='padding' keyboardVerticalOffset={50} style={styles.screen}>
     // Add all your FieldContainers here
</KeyboardAvoidingView>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    screen: {
        flex: 1,
        justifyContent: 'center',
        alignItems: 'center'
    }
});
```